# Formula to link contacts using unique id number

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I am working on a data set and I am trying to link several communications between team-members and contacts.  I have 2 sheets, one with contacts- each row has a name, unique id, phone, and email.  The next sheet has rows that include either phone, email or name, and the communication.

I have a formula from this previous question [Linking several contacts to a single ID in Google Sheets or R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55229460/linking-several-contacts-to-a-single-id-in-google-sheets-or-r/55229972#55229972)

And I am trying to use the formula but I am getting an error and I cannot figure out why/where the problem is.

Here is the example data set with the formula: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N9y9Aes4mXrKnVi7kfwUsYwGF6qKykZEtaq9gXxUFhc/edit?usp=sharing

I have tried rewriting the formula and reviewing it but I am stuck.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2:C, {Copy of contacts!D2:D,Copy of contacts!B2:B;
                                     Copy of contacts!C2:C,Copy of contacts!B2:B;
                                     Copy of contacts!A2:A,Copy of contacts!B2:B}, 2, 0) ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sheet names include spaces - so must be surrounded by `'`s.

Answer (score -1):

try like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2:C, {'Copy of contacts'!D2:D, 'Copy of contacts'!B2:B;
                                     'Copy of contacts'!C2:C, 'Copy of contacts'!B2:B;
                                     'Copy of contacts'!A2:A, 'Copy of contacts'!B2:B}, 2, 0)))
```